# Can I use nohup in a conda environment?

Tags: linux, ssh, nohup, datascience-anaconda

I should run a program in a conda environment in a remote linux server connected via ssh, which takes really long. Can I use nohup so I can logout? Will there occur any problem due to conda environment or how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `screen` or `tmux` instead. These "terminal multiplexers" will allow you to create a separate session from which you can "detach" and leave it running in the background. You can even log out, and then log back in to reattach to that session. I use it for any long-running task (e.g., running `rsync`) I want to run in the background.

Here’s a quick intro to `screen` that explains the idea: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-screen-on-linux-to-detach-and-reattach-your-terminal-2f52755ff45e

Comment: The link that you posted seems to be nonfunctional at the moment. It would be better to include the essential information in your answer than to rely on external sites whose contents may change or go away without warning.